# Writing code without using many if else statements

Tags: java

Here is my code logic with if and else if,

```
Search search = new Search(); 
Request request = new Request()
Client client = new Client();

String typeA = data.getTypeA();  // data object passing as argument to method
String typeB = data.getTypeB();
String typeC = data.getTypeC();
String typeD = data.getTypeD();

if(typeA!=null) {
    search.setType("A");  
    search.setValue(typeA);  // Type A value   
    request.setSerach(search);  
    return client.invokeTypeA(request);
}
else if(typeB!=null){
    search.setType("B");  
    search.setValue(typeB);  // Type B value   
    request.setSerach(search);  
    return client.invokeTypeB(request); 
}
else if (typeC!=null){
      ... 
      ... 
    return client.invokeTypeC(request); 
}
else if(typeD!=null){
      ... 
      ... 
    return client.invokeTypeD(request); 
}
```

Here this code is working fine, but I just need to know, any other way to do the same functionality without using if and else if. Of-curse Switch is there, but I am sure some other nice approach will be available. I don't expect exact solution at least if I get to know, other approaches, I will dig deep into that and improve my coding skills. Please can I get some bast alternative approach for my functionality.

Comment: `data.getTypeX` methods should not return nullable results. It should be `data.getType` which returns 1 of 4 different implementation of an interface

Comment: Note that questions about *design* problems as opposed to *implementation* problems are often a better fit for our sister site [programmers.se]. (That said, don't ever repost something there just because someone here said to! See [A Guide To Software Engineering For Stack Overflow Users](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7183/137070) on their meta site for details on how scope and rules differ between these two Stack Exchange sites).

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand in your code you are asking for configurations to setup your search.

So in an Object Oriented development style you'd avoid asking questions like:

```
if (type is X) 
   ...
else if (type is Y) 
   ...
else if (type is Z)
```

This is considered bad OO design.

The OO way is to use dynamic dispatch. So you'd have a **Filter** class that is configured by the UI and then you'd make it apply changes to the search like this:

```
filter.applyOn(search);
request.setSearch(search);
client.invoke(search);
```

And then add an Enum or Class like this:

```
DataType type = data.getType();

// where
abstract class DataType {
    // lambda
    public static DataType instanceFor(....) {
        return (search) ->
            {  search.setType(this.getName()); .... };   
    }

    public abstract void applyOn(Search search);
}
```

But if this is not possible and you have to use some if-like statement consider using a Map instead like this:

```
map.put("valueA", this::methodA);
map.put("valueB", this::methodB);
map.put("valueC", this::methodC);

map.computeIfAbsent(data.getType(), (s,r,c) -> {}).apply(search,request,client);
```

That would be another way to avoid ifs.

Answer (score -1):

There is no 'drop in' answer; if there had been, that would mean there are 2 ways to do the exact same thing and that'd be bad language design, so this is a good thing.

There are, of course, alternatives, but they aren't 'drop in' - they require the code that surrounds your if/elseif block to change.

For example, let's say that data has `.getTypeInfos()`, which returns `TypeInfo` objects. TypeInfo is something like:

```
@Value
public class TypeInfo {
    String resultText;
    SearchType type;
}

public enum SearchType {
    A, B, C, D;
}
```

NB: `TypeInfo` is a horrible name. However, your code snippet has been stripped of all contextual information.

then you could do:

```
for (TypeInfo info : data.getTypeInfos()) {
    if (info.getResultText() == null) continue;
    search.setType(info.getType());
    search.setValue(info.getResultText());
    request.setSearch(search);
    return client.invoke(request);
}
```

Java is highly nominal and structured; once you decide to make a method named `getTypeA` and a method named `getTypeB`, that's it - it is now very difficult to attempt to write code that where the concept of the **name** of the method to be invoked is a parameter. So, don't do that. if `getTypeA()` and `getTypeB()` are similarly structured, make a method called `getType(Type t)` or whatnot.

If you write a bevy of methods named `typeA`, `typeB`, etcetera, yeah, you tend to end up with loads of code and a ton of long if/elseif chains. Which is why you should generally not be doing that.